# DAX Calculate Formula with both "AND" and "OR" filters (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Environment: PowerBI

I had a DAX formula that worked as expected when I had just one filter:
`# Bot Responses = CALCULATE([countUniqueActivityId], customEvents[EventName]="BotMessageSend" )`.

However there is an additional filter I need to add, where it is not enough that one of 2 other conditions must be met:
`customEvents[cd_Text]<>""` or `customEvents[cd_Attach]<>""`

What is the correct syntax to have 'AND' and 'OR' conditions together?

I tried:

`CALCULATE([countUniqueActivityId], customEvents[EventName]="BotMessageSend", OR(customEvents[cd_Text]<>"", customEvents[cd_Attach]<>""))`

But that results in error:

> A single value for column 'EventName' in table 'customEvents' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

EDIT: it doesn't show the error message anymore, but it doesn't return any values either

Comment: You can try CALCULATE([countUniqueActivityId], customEvents[EventName]="BotMessageSend", customEvents[cd_Text]<>"" || customEvents[cd_Attach]<>"") -- I've used the || operator instead of the OR().

Comment: @Max I don't think that works for different columns. See the Complex Filter Arguments section here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/

Comment: @Max, thank you, this did actually work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading this article for more details but one possibility is the following:

```
CALCULATE (
    [countUniqueActivityId],
    customEvents[EventName] = "BotMessageSend",
    FILTER (
        ALL ( customEvents[cd_Text], customEvents[cd_Attach] ),
        OR ( customEvents[cd_Text] <> "", customEvents[cd_Attach] <> "" )
    )
)
```

Consider a KEEPFILTERS version if you want to add to the existing filter context rather than replace it.

```
CALCULATE (
    [countUniqueActivityId],
    KEEPFILTERS ( customEvents[EventName] = "BotMessageSend" ),
    KEEPFILTERS (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( customEvents[cd_Text], customEvents[cd_Attach] ),
            OR ( customEvents[cd_Text] <> "", customEvents[cd_Attach] <> "" )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first version and it worked.  I'm assuming you mean this article from your comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/ ?